# MySQL multiple relational between pictures and categories

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I'm currently struggling with creating an appropriate query in MySQL with several joins and conditions. I already found a similiar question [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016257/mysql-select-where-in-but-not-in-with-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016257/mysql-select-where-in-but-not-in-with-join)) which lead me to make the query at the bottom of the post. However this is not working correctly.

Take a look at the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ab0e/2 for the database schema. (I dont know how to make these nice text-formated ones)

### **Current database schema:**

**sketch_category**

```
categoryID  int(10)
name    varchar(245)    
rank    tinyint(4)
grouped tinyint(4)
```

**sketch_picture**

```
picture_id  bigint(20)
picture_name    varchar(45) N
picture_url varchar(125)
```

**sketch_tag**

```
tag_id(20)
tag_name bigint(20)
rank int(11)
```

**sketch_picture_category**

```
picture_id  bigint(20)
category_id int(11)
```

**sketch_picture_tag**

```
picture_id  bigint(20)
tag_id bigint(20)
```

---

The `sketch_picture_category` is responsible for the relation from `sketch_picture` to `sketch_category` and so is `sketch_picture_tag` responsible for the relation of `sketch_picture` to `sketch_tag`.

**I ran into several issues:**
A simple query including an `OR` statements is working fine. However as mention above any other AND statement wont give me any resulsts.

**Possible queries could be:**
Let's assume I want to look for the category:

- Want to have all pictures within the category "female" AND "male" AND "clothed" (but not all others)
- Want to have all pictures within the category "female" AND "male" AND "clothed" AND "nude" (but not all others)
- Want to have all pictures within the category "stillifee" (but not all others)
- etc.

SO far I went with this query here, but it doesn't fuflly work on all queries. It only works if I have different categories at once - so "female and male" but adding "clothed and nude" doesnt't work anymore.

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT * FROM sketch_picture p
JOIN sketch_picture_category pc1 ON p.picture_id = pc1.picture_id and pc1.category_id = 1
JOIN sketch_picture_category pc2 ON p.picture_id = pc2.picture_id and pc2.category_id = 4
JOIN sketch_category c1 ON pc1.category_id = c1.categoryID
JOIN sketch_category c2 ON pc2.category_id = c2.categoryID
LEFT JOIN sketch_picture_tag pt1 ON p.picture_id = pt1.pictures_id
LEFT JOIN sketch_picture_tag pt2 ON p.picture_id = pt2.pictures_id
WHERE pt1.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 6) AND pt2.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 6) OR pt1.tag_id IS NULL OR 
pt2.tag_id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.picture_id
```

**RESULTS:**

```
+------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+--------+------+---------+------------+------+------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+
| picture_id | picture_name | picture_url                             | picture_id | category_id | picture_id | category_id | categoryID | name   | rank | grouped | categoryID | name | rank | grouped | pictures_id | tag_id | pictures_id | tag_id |
| 1          | Nude Women   | Art_Nudes___C_11_by_mjranum_stock.jpg   | 1          | 1           | 1          | 4           | 1          | female | 1    | 0       | 4          | nude | 2    | 0       | NULL        | NULL   | NULL        | NULL   |
| 2          | Nude Women 2 | Art_Nudes___C_16_by_mjranum_stock_1.jpg | 2          | 1           | 2          | 4           | 1          | female | 1    | 0       | 4          | nude | 2    | 0       | NULL        | NULL   | NULL        | NULL   |
| 5          | nude women   | The_Dive_by_mjranum_stock.jpg           | 5          | 1           | 5          | 4           | 1          | female | 1    | 0       | 4          | nude | 2    | 0       | NULL        | NULL   | NULL        | NULL   |
+------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+--------+------+---------+------------+------+------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+
```

However the mentioned unworking query with no results:

```
SELECT * FROM sketch_picture p
JOIN sketch_picture_category pc1 ON p.picture_id = pc1.picture_id and pc1.category_id = 1 and pc1.category_id = 2
JOIN sketch_picture_category pc2 ON p.picture_id = pc2.picture_id and pc2.category_id = 3 and pc2.category_id = 4
JOIN sketch_category c1 ON pc1.category_id = c1.categoryID
JOIN sketch_category c2 ON pc2.category_id = c2.categoryID
LEFT JOIN sketch_picture_tag pt1 ON p.picture_id = pt1.pictures_id
LEFT JOIN sketch_picture_tag pt2 ON p.picture_id = pt2.pictures_id
WHERE pt1.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 6) AND pt2.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 6) OR pt1.tag_id IS NULL OR 
pt2.tag_id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.picture_id
```

The supposed results should be shown ALL pictures within `category 1 (female) AND  2 (male)` which also have the `category 3 (clothed) and 4 (nude)`

Another way I tried was this:

```
SELECT * FROM sketch_picture p
inner join sketch_picture_category pc on(p.picture_id = pc.picture_id )
inner join sketch_category c on (c.categoryID = pc.category_id) 
WHERE pc.category_id = 1 OR pc.category_id = 3
GROUP BY p.picture_id
```

which produces these wrong results - I would just need pictures with category 1 AND 3 (female and clothed). THis however produces EVERY female and EVERY clothed picture :

```
+------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+------------+---------+------+---------+
| picture_id | picture_name            | picture_url                                      | picture_id | category_id | categoryID | name    | rank | grouped |
| 1          | Nude Women              | Art_Nudes___C_11_by_mjranum_stock.jpg            | 1          | 1           | 1          | female  | 1    | 0       |
| 2          | Nude Women 2            | Art_Nudes___C_16_by_mjranum_stock_1.jpg          | 2          | 1           | 1          | female  | 1    | 0       |
| 3          | clothed man             | fly___3_by_mjranum_stock-d48bpkr.jpg             | 3          | 3           | 3          | clothed | 2    | 0       |
| 4          | clothed_women           | mervilina_by_mervilina-d6n71qa.jpg               | 4          | 1           | 1          | female  | 1    | 0       |
| 5          | nude women              | The_Dive_by_mjranum_stock.jpg                    | 5          | 1           | 1          | female  | 1    | 0       |
| 20         | abrham lincoln          | Abraham_Lincoln_head_on_shoulders_photo_portrait | 20         | 3           | 3          | clothed | 2    | 0       |
| 21         | women female head       | Vicki-Head-4.jpg                                 | 21         | 1           | 1          | female  | 1    | 0       |
| 22         | head-in-hands-sculpture | head-in-hands-sculpture.jpg                      | 22         | 3           | 3          | clothed | 2    | 0       |
| 23         | old women               | 8763_10105_combobw_mix2.jpg                      | 23         | 1           | 1          | female  | 1    | 0       |
+------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+------------+---------+------+---------+
```

If I change the statement to from "OR" to "AND" it will produce 0 results

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ab0e/2

Comment: You've mentioned possible queries, but what is the one you are having trouble with?

Comment: Well, its everything but just one or 2 different countries with the Condition OR.

Everything else doesnt work. So something like this in line 2 & 3 doesnt work - `JOIN sketch_picture_category pc1 ON p.picture_id = pc1.picture_id and pc1.category_id = 1 AND pc1.category_id = 2
JOIN sketch_picture_category pc2 ON p.picture_id = pc2.picture_id and pc2.category_id = 3 and pc2.category_id = 4`
`

Which should show all male, female, nude and clothed pictures in those categories. (see the AND's added after the first AND in the first 2 joins)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just not sure what you mean. Can you edit your question to show an expected output table with one of your queries? You mentioned countries in your comment, do you mean categories?

Comment: Auto correction ... . I'm sorry - I meant categories.

Comment: Question edited and more data.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your data all that clearly, but my thinking is this:

You're going to provide like a multiple selection of attributes in a front-end somewhere, and you need a means of finding those pictures that have all of those attributes but no others, and which is reasonably simple.

Is this estimation correct?

Assuming this is about right, well, the reasonably simple part might not be so easy, but my thinking is that you need to do something like this: (This isnt mysql, I don't know the syntax for mysql, you'll need to translate)

```
select category_id into temporary_category_table from sketch_category
where Category in ('male', 'female', ...) --selections applicable
```

Get all pictures, with any category_id in temporary_category_table into another table, I'll call it all_possible_data. This data will need to contain picture_id and every category_id existing for each picture_id. You're probably in a better position to write this than me, as I dont understand the data clearly. All_possible_data will contain distinct picture_id - category_id combinations.

With this table you then need a means of dynamically finding only those pictures that have all the category_ids existing in temporary_category_table appearing in all_possible_data.

This isnt really simple due to the need to support an indefinite number of categories.

My feeling is that the easiest way to do it, would be to use a loop which progressively consumes the data put into temporary_category_table, to programmatically build the sql statement which delivers the data, something like this:

```
select @attrib_no = 1

select @category_id = min(category_id) from temporary_category_table
delete temporary_category_table where category_id = @category_id

select @sql = "SELECT a.picture_id INTO temporary_result_table FROM ("
select @sql = "SELECT DISTINCT picture_id FROM all_possible_data WHERE category_id = "
select @sql = @sql + str(@category_id) + ") a"

while (select count(*) from temporary_category_table) > 0 begin
    select @category_id = min(category_id) from temporary_category_table
    delete temporary_category_table where category_id = @category_id
    select @sql = @sql + " INNER JOIN (SELECT picture_id FROM all_possible_data" 
    select @sql = @sql + " WHERE category_id = " + str(@category_id) + ") a"
    select @sql = @sql + str(@attrib_no) + " on a.picture_id = a" + str(@attrib_no) + ".picture_id"
    select @attrib_no = @attrib_no + 1
end
```

Then running @sql will create temporary_result_table with those picture_ids that have all of the selected categories, but not any pictures that have none or only some of these categories.

This logic doesnt consider any other categories not in the selections with picture_ids may have.

Hope this helps, or at least gives you some ideas.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I updated my question to make it more clear.
Yea your estimation is about correct. So you would kinda loop through every picture? However I'm kinda new to your @sql - Code and not understanding it at the moment how it works.
What would all_possible_data contain?

Comment: Now that you've added the tables... all_possible_data is a subset of the sketch_picture_category table. It contains the distinct rows from that table for every picture with any one of the categories being searched for. ie SELECT DISTINCT picture_id, category_id FROM sketch_picture_category WHERE category_id IN (1, 3, etc)